# What is the best way to introduce XML Configuration of a Spring Portlet?

Tags: xml, spring, portlet, opentext

I have been trying, unsuccessfully, to define some primitive constants in my Spring Portlet that can be used for application defaults. I want them to be defined in an XML file.

This sounds like it should be an easy issue, but the combination of **Spring 2.5** and **Vignette** is making it tough. Because I am using Spring, I already inject data structures into my portlet by defining data structures using things like

```
<util:list></util:list>
```

in the Context Configuration xml file. However, Spring does not allow for a mechanism to introduce single primitives like strings and ints using this paradigm.

I have been trying to introduce this data via the **portlet.xml** file. I tried adding **"init-param"** nodes, but it seems to me that this is for specific parameters related to back-end configuration and should not (and can not) be used for application specific variables.

Currently my Controller implements **PortletConfigAware** and I would somehow expect to be able to define parameters in an XML file that will be available through the PortletConfig object (which contains the PortletConfig.getInitParameter("PARAMETER_NAME") method).

I am using Vignette (OpenText), but want to use a modality that is vendor-independent... ideally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may put your config file somewhere in WEB-INF/path/to/config.xml

Then, use the following path to get it back:

```
String pathToConfig = portletConfig.getPortletContext().getRealPath("/") + File.separator + "WEB-INF" + ...;
```

Hope this helps,
Philippe

Comment: Yes, what worked for me in the end was establishing these values in the PortletPreferences